# Pandas length miss match, handling json with different length

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple JSON that i am trying to parse using pandas and populate that data in table but due to different json ouputs i am facing "Length missmatch issue"

I have two jsons.

Json 1

```
{
   "extract":{
      "details":{
         "name":"John Smith",
         "region":null,
         "add":"56 Street",
         "state":ZL,
         "exam":{
            "lastexam":null
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Json 2

```
{
   "extract":{
      "details":{
         "name":"Will Smith",
         "region":Jonsberg,
         "add":"3rd Street",
         "state":TO,
         "exam":{
            "lastexam":{
               "examnumber":"6789",
               "subject_name":"Chemistry",
               "exam_time":"2020-03-06T20:21:22"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What i am looking for use dataframes and parse and populate table like following using pandas

```
**Name,region,add,state,exam_number,subject_name,exam_time**

John Smith,null,56 Street,ZL,null,null,null

Will Smith,Jonsberg,3rd street,TO,6789,Chemistry,2020-03-06 20:21:22
```

I am able to extract available column but how do achieve and form a a dataframe that will consider all the columns and populate null if that column does not exists in json.

How do i achieve  this using pandas ?

Answer (score 1):

see if pandas' [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) works for you :

```
from pandas import json_normalize
pd.concat((json_normalize(json1), json_normalize(json2)))
```